# Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties'

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, babeljs

Description
node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/GestureDetector.tsx: /Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/src/handlers/gestures/GestureDetector.tsx: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-shorthand-properties'
Require stack:

/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
/Users/admin/Documents/meatventory/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
Steps to reproduce
not able to run project

Snack or a link to a repository
https://github.com/aksainiarun/___meatventory___

Gesture Handler version
2.12.0

React Native version
0.67.1

Platforms
Android

JavaScript runtime
None

Workflow
None

Architecture
None

Build type
None

Device
None

Device model
No response

Acknowledgements
Yes

i solve this problem with this change when i tried to run it with android studio it located me java file with error
undefined TIRAMISU

I change it from:

Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU
to:

Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP